# Генерация из текстовых файлов Delphi

Tags: delphi

Сделала вот такой код. Суть кода в том что бы генерировать имя, фамилию и отчество из базы текстовых файлов.

```
//////////////////Процедура по которой мы получаем данные из текстовых файлов
procedure Gen(s: String; E: TEdit);
var L: TStringList;
begin
 L := TStringList.Create;
 if not FileExists(s)
  then E.Text :='Файл не найден - если нет файлов: fam.txt,nam.txt, ot.txt'
  else begin
        L.LoadFromFile(s);
        if L.Count = 0
         then E.Text := 'Файл пустой'
         else E.Text := L.Strings[Random(L.Count)];
       end;
 L.Free;
end;

//////////////////Где:
fam.txt - текстовый файл в котором список фамилий
nam.txt - текстовый файл в котором список имен
ot.txt - текстовый файл в котором список отчеств

///////Процедура генерации
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  f1:TextFile;
  s:string;
  L:TStringList;
  i:integer;
begin
L:=TStringList.Create;
 Gen('fam.txt', Edit1);
 Gen('nam.txt', Edit2);
 Gen('ot.txt', Edit3);

 L.Add(s);
 L.SaveToFile('321.txt');
end;

////////////////// Где:
В [B]Edit1[/B] - Выводятся рандомные фамилия из файла: [B]fam.txt[/B]
В [B]Edit2[/B] - Выводятся рандомные имена из файла: [B]nam.txt[/B]
В [B]Edit3[/B] Выводятся рандомные отчества из файла: [B]ot.txt[/B]
```

**И вот вопрос:** 
**Как сделать так что бы:** через **SpinEdit1**, указываю сколько строк, вида - фамилия имя отчество, генерировать и сохранить в файл. То есть, к примеру, в **SpinEdit1 ввожу значение 20** и получаю результат (**Сейчас** у меня генерируется **только одно** значение и сохраняется в текстовый файл):

```
Енотина Агафья Якововна 
Сюсин Клавдий Давидович 
Бенедиктов Терентий Остапович 
Богуна Ангелина Афанасиевна 
Беломестина Бронислава Несторовна 
Халимдаров Назар Игоревич 
Ивлева Нина Афанасиевна 
Сильвестров Вацлав Ерофеевич 
Волынкина Екатерина Иосифовна 
Молодыха Варвара Михеевна 
Нутрихин Алексей Зиновиевич 
Мелехов Казимир Венедиктович 
Овчинникова Эмилия Захаровна 
Макаркина Лидия Андрияновна 
Пашина Марианна Степановна 
Вьялицын Афанасий Моисеевич 
Быков Вениамин Михаилович 
Шентерякова Кира Якововна 
Кумовьева Инесса Георгиевна 
Удома Дина Ильевна
```

Comment: Строчка `L.Add(s);` - каким конкретно образом вы ожидали, что это будет работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  L: TStringList;
  i: integer;
begin
  L := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to SpinEdit1.Value - 1 do
    begin
      Gen('fam.txt', Edit1);
      Gen('nam.txt', Edit2);
      Gen('ot.txt', Edit3);

      L.Add(Edit1.Text + ' ' + Edit2.Text + ' ' Edit3.Text);
    end;

    L.SaveToFile('321.txt');
  finally
    L.Free;
  end;
end;
```

PS. Не забывайте освобождать память, она не бесконечная.